# deploy the database easily

Tags: sql-server, database, deployment, web-hosting

How do you easily deploy an MS SQL Server database to a third-party hosting the easiest? Nothing comes to mind except generating lots of SQL scripts and running them on the database, or calling LINQ's DataContext.CreateDatabase .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can deloy the backup of database to the server and restore it
2. You can deloy the datafiles and transaction log of database to the server and attach it
3. And, of course, you can generate a lots of sql-queries to generate the database structure and fill it with data.